# Can a monk catch and deflect a magic missile?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monk

What I'm wondering is if I can use my ‘deflect’ ability that I get from being a monk to catch and use a magic missile shot at me?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear, do you mean Magic Missile the spell, or a ranged attack with a magical ammunition?

Comment: Hi Furiousmonk907. As you might have noticed, at this site we are very fond of using tags for the game system. If you can put the [dnd-5e] tag on any future questions (assuming they are actually about D&D 5e, of course), then hopefully it won't have to go through the "on hold/reopen" dance again.

Comment: @black_fm Though I'm guessing on OP's behalf, the OP did put the [spells] tag on this question originally, so that's a good argument for this being about the _magic missiles_ spell.

Comment: Yes I did mean the spell magic missile, oh and @NathanS good job for answering on my behalf using the tags, good work 

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## No, you can't. Magic Missile is not a Ranged Weapon Attack.

The text of the Monk ability Deflect Missiles states the following:

> Starting at 3rd level, you can use your reaction to deflect or catch the missile when you are hit by a ranged weapon attack.

A Ranged Weapon Attack is an attack that is both a Ranged Attack and a Weapon Attack; Magic Missile is neither. In fact, it's not an Attack at all, since it automatically hits. As a result, Deflect Missiles does not apply to Magic Missiles.

Comment: Ok thx for telling me I was just wondering

Comment: The system's been clarified; feel free to edit your answer if needed and then undelete it.